# Quiero mostrar una frase desde un archivo . json en react, pero estas no se muestran. (El archivo .json contiene un objeto)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Esta es mi app. En la parte donde está `<Frases></Frases>` es donde está colocado el componente con los textos pero en este caso no los muestra.

```
import './App.css';
import Frases from './Components/Frases'

import Twitter from './twitter-logo-3.png';
import Platon from './pngegg.png'
import Yano from './Ya no hay nadie que.mp3'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='Box'>
        <div className='Platon-hover'>
          <img className='Platon' src={Platon} alt='platon'></img>
        </div>
        <div className='Box-child'>
          <Frases></Frases> `Aqui se deberian mostrar las frases xd`
          <a href='twitter.com/intent/tweet' target='_blank'><img src={Twitter} className='Twitter-logo' alt='Logo de twitter'></img></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <audio src={Yano} controls></audio> 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

Este es mi componente `<Frases></Frases>` donde se deberían mostrar los  textos, creo que absolutamente todo está bien pero en algo estoy fallando para que no se muestren por pantalla correctamente.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import datos from './textos.json'

class Frases extends Component {
   
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{datos}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Frases
```

---

Este es mi objeto con los textos que se deberían mostrar, pero no se muestran al hacer el componente de `<Frases></Frases>`, no sé por qué, quiero hacer un botón para irlos mostrando pero pensé que así se mostraría algo.

```
  {
        "textos":  [
            {
                "frase": "Ganar lo es todo",
                "autor": "Ayanokoji"
            },
            {
                "frase": "El iq solo mide el razonamiento logico de las personas",
                "autor": "Alejandro Cullen"
            },
            {
                "frase": "Si crees que algo importa lo haras sin importar que",
                "autor": "Elon Musk"
            },
            {
                "frase": "Si puedes imaginarlo, puedes programarlo",
                "autor": "Difunto"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Respuesta en inglés de Darren Baldwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72236214/17127043)

No puedes cargar un objeto como JSX, tienes que iterarlo y renderizar JSX o convertirlo a un string (texto).

```
return (
  <div>
    {datos.textos.map(texto => (
      <div className="textContainer">
        <div className="text">{texto.frase}</div>
        <div className="author">{texto.autor}</div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Lo anterior renderizaría cada uno de los textos. Y lo siguiente renderizaría el objecto como string.

```
return (
  {JSON.stringify(datos)}
)
```

Comment: Gracias amigo eres el mejor!, lo probaré mañana a ver si funciona <3

Comment: En que parte coloco lo de JSON.stringify? en el componente, la app, o en el json?

Comment: @Alejandro Cullen en el .json no puedes, pues es JSON es un objecto de JavaScript, puedes colocarlo donde lo necesites, lo único que hace es convertir un objeto json a texto, en mi respuesta está puesto en el componente.